# How to remove last alphabet in a word using regular expression python

Tags: python, nlp, python-re

'''
string = (" qtoday X fridayq qblue aqb")
string = re.sub('^ q+', '', string)
string

## I want to remove only aplhabet q which is in the starting of the word and ending of a word...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
inp = "qtoday X fridayq qblue aqb"
output = re.sub(r'\bq|q\b', '', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
today X friday blue aqb
```

The regex pattern `\bq|q\b` matches the letter `q` when it is either preceeded or proceeded by a word boundary, i.e. it is the starting or ending letter in a word.

One edge case here might be if you wanted to preserve `q` should it appear standalone, e.g.

```
inp = "qtoday q fridayq aqb"
output = re.sub(r'\bq(?=\w)|(?<=\w)q\b', '', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
today q friday aqb
```

Here, we check in the regex pattern that the `q` is preceeded/followed by at least one other word character, to spare the standalone `q`.